# Ruby function calling, stating the module

Tags: ruby, function, module

Is it possible to include a module in a way so that i can only call it by specifically stating which module the function belongs to?

So that, if I have a 'math' class, and function 'average', within it, then I could only call it by stating math::average, or something similiar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the method as a `self` method.

```
module Greeter
  def self.hello
    "Hello World"
  end
end

puts Greeter.hello
# => "Hello World"
```